# Getting proper input for password activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am preparing a password activity and I want to get the proper input for it.
I am using the code

```
while(counter<5){
        switch(counter){
            case 1:pwdField();
                   counter++;
                break;
            case 2:pwdField2();
                   counter++;                    
                break;
            case 3:pwdField3();
                   counter++;                   
                break;
            case 4:pwdField4();                  
                   counter++;                      
                break;
        }

    }
```

pwdField are the methods that contain listeners for buttons. But for some reason only the third textView receives input. It doesnt break off after the input is received. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: what is initial value of `counter`?? Are you incrementing `counter` by 1 in your while loop

Comment: I have initialized it as static int counter=1;

Comment: debug your code,put a watch at counter, check if code line executes inside all switch case possible....

Answer (score 0):

Moved from comments:

Why do you have the while loop? If the while loop condition is met and counter is not negative then the loop will go into a case and break out of the loop, thus only going through it once. If the condition is not met then the loop will be iterated 0 times. Why not replace the while loop with an if statement?

You may not want to have the breaks in there but I don't know the intent of this snippet.

Comment: As I said I have this code to make user enter the password before he enters into the activity.
And thanks for that. I dint realize that it wouldnt loop properly.

Comment: What was confusing about the question is that you make it seem, on the first line, that this is an activity that loads in the beginning which denies the user access to the rest of the application until a valid password is entered. Under the code you are talking about pwdFields listening for buttons. It would be confusing to a spectator because most people would think that a password activity would contain a textview and 1 enter button or something similar to enter a password into instead of 4 buttons/textviews.

Comment: Oh thats actually correct code. I have made it such that the password will be entered by selecting those buttons only. Like you see in dropbox app or applock app.

Comment: If you are referring to having a swipe-based password such as the link below, you may want to design it like a finite state machine. Have a listener for each button. When the button is clicked, if the finite state machine is in the state before it should be pressed then set it to the next state; if it isn't then reset the machine to the original state. https://lh3.ggpht.com/o0XxHLvaTa4MLrxeYx6jRSVUZldGgqMYAqg-I9T4qywVb6UOywQ2-7bKpVjZ29VLfg